# Get row of 2d array where min value is in first col

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a matrix (2d numpy array) of points (3D).

```
m = np.array([[x1, y1, z1],
              [x2, y2, z2],
              ...,
              [xn, yn, zn]])
```

I would like to find the min element (`x_min`) in first column (x values) and get the entire row of matrix where this `x_min` is. For example if `x_min` is in 3rd row it would return me, where `x_min == x_3`):

```
vector = [x_min, y_3, z_3]
```

I have this, but would like to know if there is more elegant solution:

```
min = np.min(m[:, 0])
pos = np.where(min==m[:, 0])
m[pos, :]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the answer from the near-duplicate question:

```
m[np.argmin(m[:, 0]), :]
```